# What is the best approach of using progress bar and MVVM

Tags: java, android, mvvm, android-progressbar

I want to set a progress bar every time I make a server call.

I can set `LiveData` object to hold boolean if it's currently loading or not, something like this:

```
private void getMovies() {
    Call<Movies> moviesMyCall = ApiService.getMovies().getMovies();
    _isLoading.setValue(true);
    moviesMyCall.enqueue(new MyCall<Movies>() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(@NonNull Movies response, int code) {
            _isLoading.setValue(false);
            Log.i(TAG, "onSuccess: " + code);
        }

        @Override
        public void onError(@Nullable ResponseBody body, int code) {
            Log.i(TAG, "onError: " + code);

        }
    });
}
```

And listen to `isLoading` inside my activity but it smell like code duplication to me cause I need to set this to every activity and every call in my app.

I also thought of listen to this in the `BaseActivity`, but I don't think it is good approach to hold reference to viewModel inside `BaseActivity`, and even if it is, I still need to set `isLoading` to every call.

How can I solve this problem and set progress bar in the best way?

Comment: You can set the visibility of the progressbar `true` from the fragment/activity. Then once there's a response from calling the ViewModel class, you can set the visibility `false`.

Comment: Actually that what I am doing right now, but it seems wrong to me to copy-paste this to every fragment, and copy paste the progress bar to every layout